# Ruby - replacing string via gsub and regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

How can I replace the string 'nEEdle' to get the following result:

```
"haystackhaystacknEEdlehaystack" -> "haystackhaystack<b>nEEdle</b>haystack"
```

In my application I have the search parameter only in lowercase, so I want to take the last regexp result ($~) and use it as the replacement string. The following approach doesn't work:

```
n = "needle"
haystack.gsub(/#{n}/i, "<b>#{$~}</b>")
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
heystack.g­sub(/#{n}/­i, '<b>\0</b>')
```